# My static method is not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my `recipe.js` file...

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../model/user');
require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);
const Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const reviewSchema = require('../model/review');



let recipeSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  description: {
    type: String,
  },

  steps: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  ingredients: {
    type: Array,
    default: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
  },

  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },

  postedBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },


  reviewsOfRecipe: [reviewSchema],

  numberOfRatings: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },

  totalAddedRatings: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
  },

  reviewAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
  },

  postersCreationDate: {
    type: Number,
    index: true
  },

  likedBy: {
      type: Array

  },

  reviewedBy: {
      type: Array
  }


});

// Here is my static method

recipeSchema.methods.calculateAverage = function(){

  let recipe = this;

  if (recipe.numberOfRatings === 0  && recipe.totalAddedRatings === 0){
    recipe.reviewAverage = 0;
  }
  else {


    recipe.reviewAverage = recipe.totalAddedRatings / recipe.numberOfRatings


  }


};



let Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);

module.exports = Recipe;
```

In my router file, every time a user submits a review for a recipe, the fields `numberOfRatings` and `totalAddedRatings` get incremented. And after they get incremented, my static method `calculateAverage` should run and update the document.

Here is what it looks like in my code:

```
Recipe.findOneAndUpdate({_id: recipe._id, postersCreationDate: recipe.postersCreationDate},{$inc: {numberOfRatings: 1, totalAddedRatings: reviewScore}}, {returnNewDocument: true}).then((recipe) => {

               recipe.calculateAverage();
});
```

However, every time a user submits a review, although `numberOfRatings` and `numberOfRatings` get incremented accordingly, `reviewAverage` does not.

I am thinking about setting `reviewAverage` as a virtual field instead; but I am worried that doing so would make it harder and inefficient to sort the recipes by the highest and lowest review averages.

Answer (score 0):

first some things about your findOneAndUpdate can change. Id should be sufficient to find by and 'returnNewDocument' is not an option. In mongoose it's just 'new'

```
Recipe.findOneAndUpdate({_id: recipe._id},{$inc: {numberOfRatings: 1, totalAddedRatings: reviewScore}}, {new: true}).then((recipe) => {
    recipe.calculateAverage();
});
```

The problem is that you aren't saving the average to the recipe.

```
recipeSchema.methods.calculateAverage = function(callback) {
  let recipe = this;
  if (recipe.numberOfRatings === 0  && recipe.totalAddedRatings === 0) {
      recipe.reviewAverage = 0;
  }
  else {
      recipe.reviewAverage = recipe.totalAddedRatings / recipe.numberOfRatings
  }
  recipe.save(callback);
};
```

Comment: I am tinkering with it, and it is always assuming that both `numberOfRatings` and `totalAddedRatings` are zero despite being incremented, so I still get 'reviewAverage` being zero still.

Comment: It turns out pre-save hooks are not executed on findOneAndUpdate() i'll change my answer